# How to read posts of a telegram channel by PHP and bot?

Tags: php, bots, telegram

How we can read the posts of public telegram channels by PHP and save in database?

Comment: Using PHP and MySQL

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone your comment is opinion-based, I prefer PHP and PostgreSQL >:(

Comment: What do you want to save in database? Message text, sender, id, ...?

Answer (score 1):

Please read [Telegram Bots API Documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates). If the bot is admin of the channel it can receive `channel_post` or `edited_channel_post` updates (type: `Message`).

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the answer instead of linking to external sources

Comment: @NicoHaase the bot API keeps changing, I think it's better to link to the documentation. If this is against the StackOverflow policy, I'll edit the answer :)